# How do I connect programatically the bluetooth(RN4020) with Android app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth

I am developing an Android app that is going to communicate with target miroprocessor(ARM processor) board through a bluetooth device(RN4020). 
Since the pair PIN is random for each bluetooth module, I just want the app source code to connect the app with that RN4020 module (without pairing manually since I don't know the pair PIN). 
Also, I just want to know the UUID for RN4020 module, I have tried to find the UUID through some Android app it shows more than ten UUIDs. I am confused to choose the appropriate UUID.

Here is my code:

```
private static String address = "00:1E:C0:19:DB:A6";
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002A00-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");


    connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View V)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connecting to ...                  RN4020_D694", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
                Connect();
        }
    });


public void Connect() {

    BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connecting to ... " + device, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    try {
        btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        btSocket.connect();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection made", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        try {
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            changingText.setText("Unable to end the connection");
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Socket creation failed");
    }

    beginListenForData();
}
```

When I tried to press the connect button, my app got stuck and it's not responding.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid pairing you need to go for an insecure UUID rfcomm.

Replace:

```
btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
```

with

```
btSocket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
```

Comment: Dear Sir, After replacing the above code it remains the same and its not connecting to the hardware. Can you please suggest some other source code!!!!!!

Comment: The code above just resolves the pairing downgrading at the Bluetooth socket security as you requested. I don't know what else is failing to connect without a logcat. Please, edit and add your logcat in the question to check what the IOException is catching.

Comment: when I tried to run the app in mobile it shows NULL.                     BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);                      mmDevice = device;                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection made" + mmDevice.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                               And for the above code it displays:"Connection madenull".

Comment: Sorry, that's not a complete logcat to diagnosting a connection exception. I only can guess that you are providing a wrong MAC or UUID or a combination of both, but with the poor info you're providing I can be easily guessing wrong. Your original question is answered in this response: Lowering the security of the BT socket is the way to avoid explicit pairing. For your connection problems, please, add a new question with complete logcat or nobody will be able to be aware of your problem to help you.